# Error: The site's security certificate is not trusted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ssl, amazon-ec2

I am developing a website in Ruby on Rails and i want to make it HTTPS secured for this i have copied the SSL certificates

```
(AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt,domainName.com.crt,PositiveSSLCA.crt)
```

in /etc/ssl/certs directory and create a file bundle.txt and add both of the certificate texts to that file, first the PositiveSSLCA.crt then the AddTrustUTNServerCA.crt and save this file as bundle.txt in /etc/httpd/conf directory. I have modified the httpd.conf file and add the below lines:

```
 NameVirtualHost 66.200.43.71:443
<VirtualHost 66.200.43.71:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName www.domainName.com
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
 ErrorLog logs/errorlogs
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/domainName.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/domainName.com.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/PositiveSSLCA.crt
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/bundle.txt
SetEnvIf User-Agent “.*MSIE.*” nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
</VirtualHost>
```

When we did the restart of Apache Server everything worked fine but when we run the URL on browser using "https" we are receiving this error "The site's security certificate is not trusted!"

We tried many solutions available on net as
1.http://blog.futtta.be/2011/09/20/how-to-fix-ssl-errors-in-mac-os-x-browsers/
2.http://ananthakrishnanravi.wordpress.com/2012/04/15/configuring-ssl-and-https-for-your-website-amazon-ec2/

None of the above worked for us. Can any one of you please guide us through this. Not sure what exactly is missing here in my configuration of SSL certificates.

Any idea or help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ or similar?

Comment: I have an error "Certificate not valid for domain name" during this process....

Comment: The domain name that you use to access your host must match the domain name you used in the certificate signing request. If you don't have a wildcard certificate, then you can't use the cert for subdomains.